# Can I run a subset of tests from one Github repo in Test Kitchen?

Tags: test-kitchen, inspec

I reached the point where I think it makes sense to put my inspec tests in a different repo than my Chef cookbook. I just copied all dirs under `test/integration` into a new dir and created a repo from that. There are subdirs `common`, `master`, and `worker`. I'm not sure how best to manage this given my Test Kitchen setup.

Original `kitchen.yml` content:

```
suites:
  - name: master
...
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/common
        - test/integration/master
...
```

New content based on reading the docs:

```
suites:
  - name: master
...
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - git@github.com:redacted/inspec-redacted.git
...
```

As soon as I wrote this, I looked for some way to choose only the 2 desired dirs `common` and `master` but I don't see this documented. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could narrow it down with specific controls in your suite:

```
verifier:
  inspec_tests:
    - git@github.com:redacted/inspec-redacted.git
  controls:
    - xyz
```